# What SELECT $ does in MS SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

What's the purpose of

```sql
SELECT $
```

in MS SQL? I've googled but I can't understand why what I am searching is wrong because I get no results. All I know is that this query returns

```sql
.0000
```

Edit: I understand that the questions is duplicate but the answer for mine is by far better explained.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an implicit conversion to `MONEY`.

Clues:

```
SELECT ISNUMERIC($);   -- 1
SELECT ISNUMERIC('$'); -- 1

SELECT CONVERT(money, $);   -- 0.00
SELECT CONVERT(money, '$'); -- 0.00

-- even empty strings and commas behave this way:
SELECT CONVERT(money, '');   -- 0.00
SELECT CONVERT(money, ',');  -- 0.00

-- as do pound, euro, cent, and I'm sure many others:
SELECT CONVERT(money, £), CONVERT(money, €), CONVERT(money, ¢); -- 0.00, 0.00, 0.00
```

But most conclusive:

```
SELECT SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(x, 'BaseType')
FROM (SELECT $) AS y(x); -- money
```

Comment: I see, thank you very much for your answer.

Comment: About the edit amazing, I am definately saving this.